# Cannot connect to a mobile broadcast network using python

Tags: python, windows

I'm using Python to try to connect Windows to a MBN using a Tele2 Huawei Mobile USB dongle. My goal is to automate some tests. The dongle is well connected to the PC so it does not appear to be the problem. Here is my code:

```
import os
from time import sleep
import subprocess


class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        self.interface_name = "Cellular"

    def connect(self):
        print('''C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c netsh mbn connect interface=Cellular connmode=name name="Unnamed network 2"''')
        res = self.__sys_cmd('''C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c netsh mbn connect interface=%s connmode=name name="Unnamed network 2"''' % self.interface_name)
        pirnt("CONNECTION OUTPUT STRING")
        sleep(5)
        self.__is_connected()



    def __sys_cmd(self, batcmd):
        p = subprocess.Popen(batcmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        out = p.stdout.read()
        err = p.stderr.read()

        return out + err

    def __is_connected(self):
        connection_label = ["tat de linterface", "Interface State"]
        connection_state = [": connect", ": Connected"]
        connected = False
        res = self.__sys_cmd(r'''C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c netsh mbn show connection interface=%s''' % self.interface_name)
        print(r'''C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c netsh mbn show connection interface=%s''' % self.interface_name)
        print("IS CONNECTED OUTPUT STRING", res)
        res = str(res)
        res = res.split('\n')
        for line in res:
            if any(x in line for x in connection_label) and any(x in line for x in connection_state):
                connected = True
        print("IS CONNECTED FINAL JUDGMENT", connected)
        return connected


def main():
    Dongle = Test()
    Dongle.connect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, this code does not work as intended. It blocks at the attempt to connect Windows to the MBN and returns the following error from the system command line:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c netsh mbn connect interface=Cellular connmode=name name="Unnamed network 2"
('CONNECTION OUTPUT STRING', 'The following command was not found: mbn connect interface=Cellular connmode=name "name=Unnamed network 2".\r\n')
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c netsh mbn show connection interface=Cellular
('IS CONNECTED OUTPUT STRING', 'The following command was not found: mbn show connection interface=Cellular.\r\n')
('IS CONNECTED FINAL JUDGMENT', False)
```

When I enter the commands by myself in a command prompt (C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe), it works fine and Windows get connected to the network.
The expected result is something like this displayed in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\production>C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c netsh mbn connect interface=Cellular connmode=name name="Unnamed network 2"


C:\Users\production>C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c netsh mbn show connection interface=Cellular

Connection information for interface Cellular:
-------------------------------------
    Interface State       : Connected
    Register State        : Roaming
    Register Mode         : Manual
    Provider Name         : UnNamed
    Provider Id           : 00140
    Roaming text          :
    Provider Data Class   : EDGE
    Number of connections : 1

      Serial number #1
        Connection Id         : 1392
        Access Point Name     : internet
```

I managed to reproduce the error given by Python using a terminal in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe
From there, I get *The following command was not found: mbn connect interface=Cellular connmode=name "name=Unnamed network 2"*

So I thought the bug was Python (or my IDE, PyCharm) using the wrong terminal, so I checked the environment variables. The ComSpec environment variable is set to C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

I tried this using Python 2.7 32-bits and also with Python 3.8 64-bits with the same result.
I am using Windows 10 64-bits

Anybody has an idea about why it works fine when I use a terminal, but doesn't when using Python to execute the exact same commands? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I forgot to point out that I was using Python with Miniconda3 and a conda environment. I reinstalled Python 2.7, then I created a pipenv virtual environment instead of a conda one. It seems like it was the source of the problem, and the code now works fine.